# Get right object in callback

Tags: javascript

I have target object

```
function Foo() {
    this.someVar = 'some var';
};

Foo.prototype.callback() {
    console.log(this);
};
```

And object, that will call this callback

```
function Bar(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
};

Bar.prototype.onSomeAction = function() {
    this.callback();
};
```

And initial code

```
foo = new Foo();
bar = new Bar();

bar.callback = foo.callback;
bar.onSomeAction();
```

Result: i have logged to console Bar()'s context instead of Foo().
**How can i get context of Foo() in the Foo() callback?**

PS: I tried closures

```
Foo.prototype.callback() {

    var foo = this;
    return function(foo) {
        console.log(foo);
    };
};
```

but it does nothing. I have not fully understanding of the closures :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bar.callback = foo.callback.bind(foo);
```

You can polyfill `Function.prototype.bind()` if necessary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility

Comment: Doesn't bind rely on call or apply ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your original code didn't work is that the value of `this` inside of a method call is the value of the object it's being called on. That means when you say:

```
bar.callback = foo.callback;
```

And then you call:

```
bar.callback();
```

The code defined here:

```
Foo.prototype.callback = function () {
    console.log(this);
};
```

gets called with `this` being a reference to `bar` because `bar` is to the left of the `.` on the method call. So whenever you assign a function as an object property, calling it on that object will call it with the object as `this`.

You could also have written:

```
function callback() {
  console.log(this);
}
bar.callback = callback;
bar.callback();
```

And you would find that `this` still references `bar`.

In fact, if you call the plain function `callback();` as defined above, you'll find that `this` is a reference to the global object, usually `window` in web browsers. That's because all global variables and functions are properties of `window`, so `callback();` is implicitly `window.callback();`

The fact that the value of `this` depends on what object is calling a function can be a problem when passing callbacks around, since sometimes you want `this` to reference the original object the function was a property of. The bind method was design to solve this problem, and Yuri Sulyma gave the right answer:

```
bar.callback = foo.callback.bind(foo);
```

However, the way you would do this using closures is to capture an instance of Foo within an anonymous function that calls the correct method on the correct object:

```
foo = new Foo();
bar = new Bar();

bar.callback = function () {
  foo.callback();
};
bar.onSomeAction();
```

Which is essentially what bind does. In fact, we call write our own naive version of bind using a closure:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (obj) {
  var fn = this;
  return function () {
    fn.call(obj);
  };
};
```

`call` let's you call a function with the value of `this` explicitly defined. This allows you to "set the context" the function is called in so that it's the same as calling `obj.fn()` when you call `bar.callback()`. Since when we call `foo.callback.bind(foo);`, `obj` is `foo` and `fn` is `foo.callback`, the result is that calling `bar.callback()` becomes the same as calling `foo.callback()`.

That's where Dalorzo's answer comes from. He uses `call` to explicitly set the context.

There's also another function for setting the context called `apply` that also takes an array representing the arguments for the function as its second argument. This allows us to write a more complete version of bind by taking advantage of the special `arguments` variable:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (obj) {
  var fn = this;
  return function () {
    fn.apply(obj, arguments);
  };
};
```

Comment: Personally, I avoid using `this` in callback functions and stick to closures instead. That way, the callback will behave the same exact way when called no matter what object it's a property of.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! But i'm not so familiar with closures, and this is my first complex JS based app.

Comment: A closure is just a fancy way of letting you say "run this code as though it were being run where it was written instead of where it's called". This is perfect for a callback in an event-based API, because most of the time, what you're doing next in the callback is in the same context as what you just did, so you want access to all the same variables and everything. All you have to do is wrap some code in a function and pass it along as a callback. Browse some NodeJS code sometime (there's plenty of good examples), and you'll find lots of anonymous functions as arguments to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these changes:

1. Use `call` to set context:

   ```
   bar.onSomeAction.call(foo);
   ```
2. And I think your `callback` function needs to change to:

   ```
   Foo.prototype.callback=function() {    
       console.log(this);    
   };
   ```